# Spring Data JPA, constructor with entity id instead of entity instance

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have Spring boot application with Spring Data JPA.
I want to create constructor that will accept foreign key entity id, instead of entity object.

I found that I can use session.load(Source.class, sourceId) from Hibernate (and it even will not make additional request to database, exactly what I need), but I have no idea how to use it in entity.

Is it possible? What is best practice to handle the issue?

The example below illustrated what I wanted.

```
@Entity
public class Article implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @JsonProperty(value = "source")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "source_id", nullable = false)
    private Source source;

    @Column(name = "title", nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "description", nullable = false)
    private String description;

    public Article() {
    }

    // existing constructor
    public Article(Source source, String title, String description) {
        this.source = source;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
    }

    // constructor that I need
    public Article(Integer sourceId, String title, String description, Integer sourceId) {
        this.source = sourceId; // some magic should be here
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

Comment: you want set id of Source ?

Comment: try  `this.source.setId(sourceId);`

Comment: Not sure if I understand, but the usage you're looking for is loading all the `Article` having an precise `source`, am I right ?

Comment: I have only source ID and I want to create Article without getting full Source entity.

Comment: I'm also searching a solution for this (passing ID of referenced entity instead of full instance). Did you ever succeed?